# Excel Macro Scatterplot

Tags: excel, vba, charts, macros

I am trying to define a VB Macro that creates a scatterplot chart from data in my NormLinear tab.  The Plot’s y-value data is in one column and the x-axis data labels are in another non-contiguous column (there aren’t any x values).   I am attempting keep the y-axis dimensions fixed, since the data is normalized.   I desire to add an acceptable y-value max and min lines to the plot at y= 0.25 and y= 2.5, or a different shading of the plot background outside of this range.

I get a chart to appear, but when I click on that tab it is altered by MS Excel – I find this weird and difficult to debug.  Also the legend still appears even though I set it to FALSE.
I am using a Mac running OSX v10.9.5 and MS Office  2011.
Your assistance is appreciated.

```
Public Sub aMakeplot()

Dim work_book As Workbook
Dim r As Integer
Dim chart_shape As Shape
Dim i As Long
Dim objSelection As Range, objSrcData As Range, objCategories As Range

Set work_book = Application.ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NormLinear").Select

Set objChart = Charts.Add

With objChart
    ' Set its properties
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Sample Mean Value for all Slides "
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -3
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 3

    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Sample Descriptions"
End With

' Create a single range from the union of
' categories and selected data, and then
' update the chart.
Set objCategories = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NormLinear").Range("h12:h23")
Set objSelection = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NormLinear").Range("p12:p23")

Set objSrcData = Union(objCategories, objSelection)
objChart.SetSourceData objSrcData

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NormLinear").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed to work fine for me in Excel 2016 for Windows. However, in some versions of Excel, if you have no data in the chart, you can't do much with chart titles and legends and other elements. Add the data as soon as you create the chart (i.e., `SetSourceData`), then attend to all of the formatting.